# I would like to autopopulate a table with a given sequence of numbers

Tags: tables

I'm hoping to autopopulate a table that does fills in the horizontal table with the sequence and  with the table below with the second column autopopulated.

```
 \documentclass[11pt, fleqn]{examdesign}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\SectionFont{\large\sffamily}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,hypcap=false]{caption}
\Fullpages
\ContinuousNumbering
\ShortKey
\class{Needed for Examdesign}%%necessary for examdesign class


\begin{document}
\begin{shortanswer}
\begin{block}
\parbox{\linewidth}{
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
    5 & 7&9&11 \\
\end{tabular}\vspace{5mm}\\
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
    \shortstack{Term\\ Number}& Term &\shortstack{Ordered\\ Pair}\\
    \hline
    1 & 5&\normalsize(1,5)\\ 
     \hline
    2 & 7&\normalsize(\enspace\enspace,\enspace\enspace)\\ 
     \hline
    3   &9 &\normalsize(\enspace\enspace,\enspace\enspace)\\ 
       \hline
    4    &11 &\normalsize(\enspace\enspace,\enspace\enspace)\\ 
       \hline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{question}hi
\begin{answer}
hello
\end{answer}
\end{question}
\end{block}
\end{shortanswer}
\end{document}
```

I would like the macro to do something like: 
\Mysequence{3,5,7,9,11}  and then output both tables to include the 3,5,7,9,11 horizontally and the table below showing the 3,5,7,9,11 in the 2nd column automatically.  Please help and thanks.
I would also like to ensure that I reset the term number each time I call the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with the `&` in automatically generated tables is known to be a bit tricky, but there exist various ways to deal with that. This answer adopts the `etoolbox` based approach from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15520). `\docsvlist` is used three times,

1. to generate the sequence of `c`s to specify the columns in the first table,
2. to fill the columns in the first column, and
3. to generate the rows of the second table.

I am not quite sure I understand the purpose of the `\parbox` here but I kept it.

```
\documentclass[11pt, fleqn]{examdesign}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{irow}
\SectionFont{\large\sffamily}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,hypcap=false]{caption}
\Fullpages
\ContinuousNumbering
\ShortKey
\class{Needed for Examdesign}%%necessary for examdesign class

\newcommand{\Mysequence}[1]{% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15520
\edef\mytabcols{}%
\renewcommand*\do[1]{\appto\mytabcols{c}}%
\docsvlist{#1}%
\edef\myflag{0}%
\edef\mytabrow{}%
\renewcommand*\do[1]{\ifnum\myflag=0
  \typeout{0}
  \appto\mytabrow{##1}%
  \edef\myflag{1}
  \else
  \appto\mytabrow{& ##1}%
  \fi
  }%
\docsvlist{#1}%
\def\mytabrows{}%
\setcounter{irow}{0}%
\renewcommand*\do[1]{%
\appto\mytabrows{\stepcounter{irow}\number\value{irow}& ##1 & 
(\number\value{irow},##1) \\ \hline}}%
\docsvlist{#1}%
\begin{tabular}{\mytabcols}
    \mytabrow \\[5mm]
\end{tabular}\par
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
    \shortstack{Term\\ Number}& Term &\shortstack{Ordered\\ Pair}\\
    \hline
    \mytabrows
\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{shortanswer}
\begin{block}
\parbox{\linewidth}{\Mysequence{3,5,7,9,11}}
\begin{question}hi
\begin{answer}
hello
\end{answer}
\end{question}
\end{block}
\end{shortanswer}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  I do have a question.  When I call the /MySequence subsequent times, is there a way to reset the term numbers so it starts at "1" again?  Currently, the term number keeps counting even for a new table.  You've been so helpful and I appreciate everything.

Comment: @E.Yu Good catch! My bad. Fixed it.

Comment: No worries.  I'm just appreciative of your help.  I think what was changed was edef to \setcounter{irow}{0}%    I'll have to try to figure out how it works.

Comment: @E.Yu Yes. I had first tried something else and forgot to change everything to the counter systematics.